# Propagating ALM parameters between called sub tests

Tags: parameters, alm, hp-quality-center

In HP ALM/QC, given :

- a Template Test `T1` with a parameter `P1`
- a Template Test `T2` with a parameter `P2`

Can I make `T1` call `T2` with the value of `P1` inserted into `P2`?

In `T1` I tried to call `T2` and pass "<<< P1 >>>" as the value for `P2`, but it did not work : when I made a new test `T3` calling `T1` with an actual value for `P1`, the parameter `P2` ended up with the raw value "<<< P1 >>>" instead of the value of the parameter `P1`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, not directly.**

Two things can be passed as a parameter value:

- The value of another parameter (using the {} syntax)
- A literal value

which means you cannot pass any kind of expression, not even the simplest form concatening two parameter values with {paramname1}{paramname2}, or a parameter value and a literal value.

**A possible workaround is** to process the Parameter value programmatically before using it.

For example, you could replace all instances of  with the value of Parameter named paramname in the string that Parameter() delivers.

(Be aware, however, that simply doing search-and-replace might not always be enough, you might need to create a parser for the syntax you create.)